# How do I split a pandas dataframe column into 3 unique columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with college basketball betting odds. I need to split the first column 'game' into 'time', 'home', 'away'. The home team is the last team listed in the 'game' dataframe.

The data is being scraped into a data frame via beautiful soup.

```
import pandas as pd # library for data analysis
import numpy as np
import requests # library to handle requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # library to parse HTML documents
url = "https://vegasinsider.com/college-basketball/odds/las-vegas/"
response=requests.get(url)
print(response.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
indiatable=soup.find('table',{'class':"frodds-data-tbl"})
df=pd.read_html(str(indiatable))
# convert list to dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame(df[0])
print(df.head())
df.columns =['game', 'open','consensus','betmgm','caesars','fanduel','draftkings','pointsbet','wynn','superbook']
df
```

[image: The scraped data frame]

I need help splitting the first column into three columns though. This is the code I am using.

`df[['time', 'home', 'away']] = df['game'].str.split(expand=True)`

I need to new data frame to look like:

`df = pd.DataFrame ({'time': ['02/02 7:00 PM'], 'home': ['Furman'], 'away': ['The Citadel']})`

[image]

Per requests, the output of `df[['game']].to_dict()` is:

```
{'game': {0: '02/02 7:00 PM  665\xa0The Citadel  666\xa0Furman'}}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please share your data as code not as image. The solution depends on how your data is formatted.

Comment: I added the code. Thanks for your response!

Comment: it would help us help you if you could copy and paste the output of running `df[['game']].to_dict()`

Comment: Pmannn please follow @piterbarg advice.

Comment: {'game': {0: '02/02 7:00 PM  665\xa0The Citadel  666\xa0Furman'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `str.split` on `"\xa0"`, and use `str.rstrip` to strip the digits on the right:

```
import string
df[['time','home','away']] = df['game'].str.split('\xa0', expand=True).apply(lambda col: col.str.rstrip(string.digits), axis=0)
df = df.drop(columns='game')
```

Output:

```
             time          home    away
0  02/02 7:00 PM   The Citadel   Furman
```